# Unit test method with jQuery and this.random() inside, in vue

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I am new to Unit test, I want to test a component with a method that inside of that method I use `this.random` function and jQuery with Jest.

I want to test if *openPost* method is called or not?

When I get a test, It throws errors `this.$ is not a function` and `this.random is not a function`.

How can I write the test?

The component:

```
<template>
    <div @click="openPost('note')" class="ml-3 text-center pointer noteBtn">
      <i class="fal color-9e fa-handshake"></i>
      <div class=" fs-14 color-50">metting</div>
    </div>
</template>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      addNewKey: '',
      addNewType: '',
      showModal: false,
      showNegoModal: false,
      data: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openPost(type, data) {
      this.addNewType = type
      if (data) this.data = data
      else this.data = {}
      this.addNewKey = this.random()
      this.$nextTick(() => {
        if (type === 'call') {
          this.$('#createContact').modal('show')
        } else if (type === 'note') {
          this.$('#createNote').modal('show')
        } else if (type === 'negotiation') {
          if (data) {
            this.showNegoModal = true
            this.$nextTick(() => {
              this.$('#CompanyNegoModal2').modal('show')
            })
          } else this.createnegopopup.show = true
        }
      })
    }
}
```

The test:

```
import { shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import component from '../../components/component'

global.Math.random = jest.fn()
global.$ = jest.fn()

describe('AddDetailToCompany', () => {
  let wrapper = null
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(component)
  })
  afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.destroy()
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })
  test('calls openPost when noteBtn is clicked', () => {
    const openPost = jest.fn()
    wrapper.find('.noteBtn').trigger('click')
    expect(openPost).toHaveBeenCalledWith('note')
    wrapper.vm.$nextTick().then(function() {
      expect(global.Math.random).toHaveBeenCalled()
      expect(global.$).toHaveBeenCalledWith('#createNote')
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested component doesn't access global `$` but instance property that needs to be mocked:

```
wrapper = shallowMount(component, { mocks: { $ } })
```

That jQuery is chainable requires to provide chainable mocks:

```
modal = jest.fn();
$ = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ modal });
```

Comment: I write this:
`test('calls openPost when noteBtn is clicked', () => {
    const modal = jest.fn()
    const $ = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ modal })
    wrapper = shallowMount(AddDetailToCompany, { mocks: { $ } })
    wrapper.find('.noteBtn').trigger('click')
    expect(wrapper.vm.random).not.toBe(undefined)
    expect(wrapper.vm.$).not.toBe(undefined)
  })` but it throws error `this.$(...).modal is not a function`.

Comment: There shouldn't be `this.$(...).modal is not a function` error if you did everything correctly because it was provided through `mocks`, you can test this with `expect(jest.isMockFunction(wrapper.vm.$().modal)).toBe(true);`. I've just checked the test and it works as expected. Please, provide a way to reproduce the error in case it persists. The error may refer to some other place where you didn't mock `$`. Btw in original test you don't return a promise from a test, you won't be able to test async code correctly, use `async` function and `await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()` in `test`.